# Order fulfilment with Akka FSM, storing state

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I am trying to build order fulfilment component with AKKA FSM. I have few basic doubts on how the state is been stored and taken further upon event from user.

**Consider states**

`ORDER_CLEAN, ORDER_INIT, ORDER_PAYMENT_WAITING, ORDER_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, ORDER_DELIVERY, ORDER_COMPLETE`

**Events as**

`EV_CART_CHECKOUT, EV_PROCEED_PAYMENT, EV_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL, EV_ITEMS_PACKED, EV_DELIVERED`

**State changes as**

```
(EV_CART_CHECKOUT, ORDER_CLEAN) -> ORDER_INIT
(EV_PROCEED_PAYMENT, ORDER_INIT) -> ORDER_PAYMENT_WAITING
(EV_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL, ORDER_PAYMENT_WAITING) -> ORDER_PAYMENT_SUCCESS
(EV_ITEMS_PACKED, ORDER_PAYMENT_SUCCESS) -> ORDER_DELIVERY 
(EV_DELIVERED, ORDER_DELIVERY) -> ORDER_COMPLETE
```

**Questions**

1. When we create FSM actors starting at `ORDER_CLEAN` with event `EV_CART_CHECKOUT`, would this actor is alive till we bring it to `ORDER_COMPLETE`(assuming we stop actor at this state) state?
2. If yes to above point, in that case as we store order status on database how do we trigger new event on that actor? Is that do we need to maintain `order_id` to actor mapping and trigger event? What if there are *10K* unique orders are currently being processed then we maintain mapping for all *10K* actors is it? If so what is best data structure for maintaining these mappings for larger number of orders?
3. In continuation to 2nd point, what if actors go down how to bring back actors to same state? Is supervisor actor only way to solve this? Or do we need to check actor status and then send event?
4. At any point of state, user might not trigger next event may be for days, then is it good to keep actor live for such longer time or is it good to create new actor with updated state?

What are the better approaches to address these problems with akka FSM

Answer (score 0):

1. If we are talking about non-persistent Actor, generally speaking, we
   can't assume it will be alive between events. You simply might
   restart or redeploy the service, so the answer to your 1. question
   is no.
2. To trigger a new event to the actor, you should create this actor initialise state machine with last valid state from the DB.
3. You could either use [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) or just read current order state from the DB and pass it to the actor
4. Actors are very lightweight objects, but talking about 10k events I would suggest to terminate actor after each transition